# Call specific PHP function with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve data from another server (testing locally) by calling a specific function within a PHP file. Currently nothing is being returned unless I manually call the function in the PHP file.

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://test.local/php/ajax/json.php',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {action: 'get_data'},
      success: function(data) {
        $json = $.parseJSON(data);
        [...]
      }
});
```

My PHP is as follows, and evidently `$_POST` is not set as the client application receives no data. Setting `$_POST['action'] = 'get_data';` manually or calling `get_data()` in the PHP file returns all the data fine.

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
  $action = $_POST['action'];
  switch ($action) {
    case 'get_data': get_data(); break;
  }
}
```

Why is `$_POST['action']` not being set by the AJAX query? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: BTW, if you use `empty()`, you don't need to use `isset()` first; `empty()` checks if it's set as well.

Comment: JSONP always uses `GET`, not `POST`.

Comment: Thanks! Setting it to `GET` works fine.